# Bitcoin RPC getbalance of address I sent coins to on regtest

Tags: json-rpc, regtest

Here is my terminal session:

```
$ echo $address
mvt7M16caMH1xoJyfWU5orjArfq97jhZ7k
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
5899.99990000
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress $address 10.0
6ed7452f8f11fe25904867b57e127a6b65cb180c2013e667e3d399c4179ff1f0
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest setgenerate true 1 
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance $address
0.00000000
```

Shouldn't the balance of this address be 10 now? I thought that by generating a block, I will have that transaction included, which will show up on the addresses balance?

Comment: Is bitcoind in regtest mode? Is the address in your wallet?

Comment: I ran `bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress`, and I also ran `bitcoind -regtest -daemon`, I think those are the two things you are looking for. If I needed to do anything outside of that, then no.

Comment: Try `getreceivedbyaddress` instead.

Comment: That worked! Now why is that? Did I mistype something some where? Am I misunderstanding a procedure?

Comment: getbalance returns the balance of an account, not an address. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list I didn't notice it at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getbalance` returns the balance of an account, not an address.  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

If there's no account by the name of mvt7M16caMH1xoJyfWU5orjArfq97jhZ7k, it will return 0.

Try using `getreceivedbyaddress` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use it like this:

```
account="123abc"
bitcoin-cli -regtest setaccount $address $account
bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance $account
10.0
```